# Firebird IBOConsole SQL Drop Table if exist not working

Tags: sql, firebird

I'm pretty new on Firebird..  trying to write a query that drops the table if exists through IBOConsole.

I have written the following sql statement,

```
EXECUTE block as
BEGIN
if (exists(
SELECT 1 FROM RDB$RELATIONS Where RDB$RELATION_NAME = 'ZZGTTUNIQUEID'))
then
execute statement 'DROP TABLE ZZGTTUNIQUEID';
END
```

but getting the following result..

```
ISC ERROR CODE:335544569

ISC ERROR MESSAGE:
Dynamic SQL Error
SQL error code = -104
Unexpected end of command - line 6, column 19
```

i'm not sure what might be wrong?

Comment: I think you need to write like this: `execute statement 'DROP TABLE ZZGTTUNIQUEID;';`

Comment: You probably need to switch the statement terminator to something other than `;` so that IBO console knows when the statement ends. Eg do `SET TERM #;`, add a `#` after the final `END` and add a `SET TERM ;#` after the last line.

Comment: hey cha,   i've tried to change the line 6 to [execute statement 'DROP TABLE ZZGTTUNIQUEID';';]  and i get [Unexpected end of command - line 7, column 19]

and...  @MarkRotteveel  i've tried

Set term #;
EXECUTE block as
BEGIN
if (exists(
SELECT 1 FROM RDB$RELATIONS Where RDB$RELATION_NAME = 'ZZGTTUNIQUEID'))
then
execute statement 'DROP TABLE ZZGTTUNIQUEID';
END#
set term;#

Problem in BindingCursor...

Comment: @HyoJiggy I am not 100% sure if you are allowed to execute DDL from within an `EXECUTE BLOCK`.

Comment: hmmm...   I want it to  check if table exist and if yes, drop that table....   how can i do that in firebird?  sounds simple, but it's becoming to be more challenging....

Comment: I just tried it with Firebird 2.5 and the query itself should work, as long as the table is not in use by a different (or the same) transaction(!). Given the (incomplete) error message you quote, the actual problem might be something else. Could you update your question with the exact query you used and the error message you received?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - are you using IBOConsole to do this?

Comment: No, I used FlameRobin

Comment: I ended up making a stored procedure to do this.

Answer (score 0):

In IBOConsole I also experienced problems using the EXECUTE BLOCK statement, resulting in a 'Problem in BindingCursor' message and not executing the statement on the database. Use IBExpert's script executive or FlameRobin instead and it will work.